# Can the derivative of an integral of a Brownian motion be calculated?

Tags: stochastic-integrals

For an equation given below:
$$ \int_0^t\phi(s)dW(s)
$$
where $W(s)$ is a Brownian Motion.
Can I calculate the derivate w.r.t $t$ as follows:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_0^t\phi(s)dW(s)\right) = (\phi(t)-\phi(0))(W(t)-W(0))
$$
?
Or is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong. The derivative does not exist. If $\phi$ is a locally square-integrable deterministic function, the process $\int_0^\cdot \phi(s) dW_s$ has the same distribution as the process $W_{\int_0^\cdot \phi^2(s) ds}$. It is not differentiable in general since $W$ is not dirrerentiable.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want to calculate $dX/dt$ where $X=B(t).\int_0^t\phi(s)dW(s)$ how should I go about it?

Comment: You cannot calculate it, it does not exist.

Comment: The derivative of $X$ does not exist but there is an integration-by-parts formula that gives $dX_t=A_t\,dB_t+B_t\,dA_t+d\langle A,B\rangle_t$. Now plug in the $dW$-integral for $A$ and calculate the covariation between $A$ and $B$.